# How to change the optimization level with Eclipse + CDT + MinGW?

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, eclipse-cdt

I am writing some C code with Eclipse + CDT + MinGW.

The compilation output always shows:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o Math.o "..\\Math.c"
```

How can I change the command line parameters such as -O0, -Wall?

(I am new to Eclipse IDE.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For GCC, the setting is in project properties => C/C++ Build => Settings => GCC C Compiler => Optimization.

[image]