# Eclipse IDE BUG - optimization level, debug level pops to NONE

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse IDE I can’t set the debug level and optimization level no matter what i do.

The problem is when i try to set the debug level and optimization options under Project Properties > C/C++ Build > Tool Settings > GCC C++ Compiler > Debugging/Optimization. After selecting any option in the pulldown box, it pops back to “None” in both boxes.

I tried to create a new workspace with a new project, i tried to erase the system workbench and install again , make new projects with different processors.

Why can’t I change these settings?
By the way in another PC everything is working.

my versions:

Eclipse IDE Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

System Workbench for STM32 - OpenOCD (for Windows 32bits)

Version: 1.16.0.201807130628 
windows 10 64 bit

Thanks 
Sergey

Comment: [This pulldown box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26690918/6505250)? Eclipse Neon is pretty old. Can you reproduce this issue with Eclipse 2018-09 (CDT 9.5.3)?

Comment: yes this pulldown box. i working with latest version of System Workbench for STM32 its eclipse with cross compiler and other stuff for ST MCU. Anyway the same installation working in my PC at work.

Comment: Sure, System Workbench for STM32 is based on Eclipse. Maybe it's a fixed or still existing Eclipse CDT bug, maybe it's a System Workbench for STM32 bug (but certainly it is not an Eclipse IDE bug, as you claim in the title). Please try to reproduce this issue with plain Eclipse CDT 9.5.3 to find it out.

Comment: I installed Version: 9.5.3.201809121146 - and made a new C project. and still the same issue i cant change the optimization level or debug level at all. may be i need to install some drivers or i need to config something?