I am getting wrong output in eclipse ide
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}},sr,sc,i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            sc=sc+arr[j][i];
        }
    }
    printf("the sum of row =%d",sc);
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            sr=sr+arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("\n the sum of column =%d",sr);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

This is my code so the Eclipse showing sum of rows is  45 and sum of columns 390948 like number but exact answer should be sum of column=45 and sum of row is 45. I tried and got answer in an online compiler.
I am expecting get answers 45 45 for both sum

I don't know about modern C, but I'm pretty sure when I used C decades ago, the initial value of uninitialized variables wasn't well-defined. Maybe you should initialize sr and sc to be 0 to start with? (I'd also strongly advise you to format your code carefully for readability, and use a consistent bracing style.)

THANK YOU SIR FOR YOUR VALU INFORMATION.KINDLY SUGGEST ME  SOMEWAYS TO CORRECT MY READABILITY AND BRACING STYLE,WHERE CAN I LEARN THOSE THINGS @JonSkeet

I'd start by turning caps lock off so that you're not shouting...

In C a stack variable (auto storage class) is uninitialized (has no meaningful value) unless you explicitly set it a value. All your variables are auto.
In your case you set i=0 and j=0 when you start a loop, but sr and sc still contain no meaningful value but garbage:

It's not necessarily all zeroes like I show here. It can be 390948 or whatever.
The compiler can warn you about this. Just turn on optimizations (e.g. -O2) in your project: (depending on your Eclipse version) go to Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings. Click on the triangle next to your compiler to see the drop down menu -> click on Optimization. On the right hand side next to Optimization Level choose from the drop down menu your desired level.
Once you do that your compiler would say:
a.c:11:15: warning: ‘sc’ is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]
   11 |             sc=sc+arr[j][i];
      |             ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
a.c:6:45: warning: ‘sr’ is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]
    6 |     int arr[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}},sr,sc,i,j;
      |                                             ^~

Then if you initialize sc=0 and sr=0 before accumulating the values in them it will work as you expect:
sr=0;
sc=0;
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
for(j=0;j<3;j++)
...

In an online IDE it worked because like in mine example out of luck values in these variables were zeroes.

thankyou sir for your valuable.i am not able to find   desired level kindly  show in a screenshot after taking optimization menu

Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689632/how-to-change-the-optimization-level-with-eclipse-cdt-mingw
